# .net 6 web api - bad "Content-Type" property in request body - return 400 status instead of 500

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, mime-types

I have an `Attachments` json array in the request payload, and each attachment has three properties:

`Name` - string and holds the name of the file to be attached.

`ContentType` - System.Net.Mime.ContentType and holds the mediatype info of the file and

`FileData` - string and holds base64encoded string of contents of the file/attachment.

Whenever `ContentType` is `null/empty` I see that the control does not even hit the controller, but the API is sending a `500 internal server error`, and the error message in the response is not helpful for the client:

`Message: This property cannot be set to an empty string. (Parameter 'value')`

Is there a way to let the API pass through whatever value is entered for this property(`mediaType` in `ContentType`) and I would like to do the validation in the API for this property and throw a 400 with a proper message. Below is the request body that is causing above error:

```
"Attachments": [
    {
      "Name": "Something.txt",
      "ContentType": {
        "Boundary": null,
        "CharSet": null,
        "MediaType": "", //this is causing the above error and I would like this one to be a bad request not a internal server error.
        "Name": "SampleContentType",
        "Parameters": [
          {
            "Key": "name",
            "Value": "SampleContentType"
          }
        ]
      },
      "FileData": "some base64 encoded string here"
    }
  ]
```

One solution to this is to use a custom ContentType model which mimics the one being used, do the validation then map it to the original one, but I want to understand why the API is throwing 500, before it even hits the controller.

Comment: can you show the action method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ConsumesAttribute` to let the framework check it.

```
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")] // example
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction { ... }
```

This will return a 415 by default if the `Consumes` criteria is not met.